# How can I tell jaxb / Maven to generate multiple schema packages?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, schema, xsd, java

Example:

```xml
</plugin>       
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.1</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
            <configuration>
             <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir1</schemaDirectory>
              <schemaIncludes>
                  <include>schema1.xsd</include>
              </schemaIncludes>
              <generatePackage>schema1.package</generatePackage>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
          <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.1</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
            <configuration>
             <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir2</schemaDirectory>
              <schemaIncludes>
                  <include>schema2.xsd</include>
              </schemaIncludes>
              <generatePackage>schema2.package</generatePackage>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
```

What happened:
Maven executes the the first plugin. Then deletes the target folder and creates the second package, which then is visible.

I tried to set target/somedir1 for the first configuration and target/somedir2 for the second configuration. But the behavior does not not change? Any ideas? I do not want to generate the packages directly in the src/main/java folder, because these packages are genereated and should not be mixed with manual created classes.

Comment: yep, got the same issue here, though Pascal's solution works near perfect.  All I need now is to get the IDE to play nice with the generated code, otherwise is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I had to specify different [`generateDirectory`](http://static.highsource.org/mjiip/maven-jaxb2-plugin/generate-mojo.html#generateDirectory) (without this, the plugin was considering that files were up to date and wasn't generating anything during the second execution). And I recommend to follow the `target/generated-sources/<tool>` convention for generated sources so that they will be imported in your favorite IDE automatically. I also recommend to declare several `execution` instead of declaring the plugin twice (and to move the `configuration` inside each `execution` element):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>schema1-generate</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir1</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>shiporder.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>com.stackoverflow.package1</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>schema2-generate</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir2</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>books.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>com.stackoverflow.package2</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc2</generateDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this setup, I get the following result after a `mvn clean compile`

```
$ tree target/
target/
├── classes
│   ├── com
│   │   └── stackoverflow
│   │       ├── App.class
│   │       ├── package1
│   │       │   ├── ObjectFactory.class
│   │       │   ├── Shiporder.class
│   │       │   ├── Shiporder$Item.class
│   │       │   └── Shiporder$Shipto.class
│   │       └── package2
│   │           ├── BookForm.class
│   │           ├── BooksForm.class
│   │           ├── ObjectFactory.class
│   │           └── package-info.class
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── shiporder.xsd
│   └── dir2
│       └── books.xsd
└── generated-sources
    ├── xjc
    │   └── META-INF
    │       └── sun-jaxb.episode
    ├── xjc1
    │   └── com
    │       └── stackoverflow
    │           └── package1
    │               ├── ObjectFactory.java
    │               └── Shiporder.java
    └── xjc2
        └── com
            └── stackoverflow
                └── package2
                    ├── BookForm.java
                    ├── BooksForm.java
                    ├── ObjectFactory.java
                    └── package-info.java
```

Which seems to be the expected result.

Comment: thanks, I actually had the same problem yesterday but momentarily gave op on it.  Your solution works almost perfectly, my only issue now is that I cannot get Eclipse to compile without error.  All is good on the command line though.  My current workaround is that I declare these folders in target as source folders and all is good.. though I'm not certain I like it much, I'd rather create a jar with the generated code and just use it directly

Comment: The eclipse plugin m2eclipse does update the build path. After generating the beans with mvc clean assembly:assembly I just run [right click on project] > [Maven] > [Update Project Configuration] and it updates the build path.

Comment: @Newtopian See @M.R.'s comment, m2eclipse will do that for you if you follow the convention I mentioned.

Comment: hmm ok then, turns out to do the same thing I did manually, only now it takes just one or two clicks.  Still strange to see target in the source folders but now it's almost free to do so I'll keep it :-)

Comment: what if the schemaDirectory is the same for all? I have many xsd's and wsdl that should be mapped to different packages. in my case all the packages end up having all the classes  (all classes in all packages)

Comment: Had to add staleFile for both the configurations
<staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.xjcStaleFlag_1</staleFile>

Comment: Any way to have a single "execution" tag for all files instead of specifying one "execution" per schema?

Comment: I know it is old question but I hope something answer me. I use that code and it works. But when I want set up same same package it always generate only one schema. For example in first execution I set com.myproject.answer and in second execution com.myproject.request .. and after source generating I have only *answer package and request is missing ... any idea how to fix it? Generate directory I set also same.

Comment: Thank you, I had this same issue and this worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: Sadly this does not work when I use the same `generateDirectoryor more than one block.

Answer (score 15):

You can use also JAXB bindings to specify different package for each schema, e.g.

```xml
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" schemaLocation="book.xsd">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.stackoverflow.book" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Then just use the new maven-jaxb2-plugin 0.8.0 `<schemas>` and `<bindings>` elements in the `pom.xml`. Or specify the top most directory in `<schemaDirectory>` and `<bindingDirectory>` and by `<include>` your schemas and bindings:

```xml
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
<schemaIncludes>
    <include>book/*.xsd</include>
    <include>person/*.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
<bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
<bindingIncludes>
    <include>book/*.xjb</include>
    <include>person/*.xjb</include>
</bindingIncludes>
```

I think this is **more convenient solution**, because when you add a new XSD you do not need to change Maven `pom.xml`, just add a new XJB binding file to the same directory.

Comment: Whilst trivial the edit to provide a syntax highlight hint does improve the legibility of the post

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. I have not get that the edit added syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is the best answer for me as I wouldn't want to keep changing the pom each time a new schema is added.

Comment: The one issue here is if book and person are in the same target namespace in the xsd. Let's say instead they had book, journal, newspaper, etc. all of which included publishable.xsd. They'd have to be in the same namespace as publishable, and thus each other, and now this breaks because you can only have one schemaBindings per namespace. I agree it's ideal, and I wish it worked for the example above, but JAXB just isn't flexible enough.

Answer (score 9):

you should change that to define the plugin only once and do twice execution areas...like the following...and the generateDirectory should be set (based on the docs)..

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>firstrun</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <generateDirectory>target/gen1</generateDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir1</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>schema1.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>schema1.package</generatePackage>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>secondrun</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <generateDirectory>target/gen2</generateDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/dir2</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>schema2.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>schema2.package</generatePackage>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It seemed to me that you are fighting against single artifact rule of maven...may be you should think about this.

Comment: The one artifact per module rule is true but... the OP is not generating two artifacts.

Answer (score 5):

i have solved with:

```xml
                        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
```

add this to each configuration ;)

Comment: You could also add it only to the `<executions>` tag. That's sufficient. `<removeOldOutput>` is set to false by default. But I can't find `<clearOutputDir>` at http://static.highsource.org/mjiip/maven-jaxb2-plugin/generate-mojo.html

Comment: For me the real solution, cause you can generate everythong in same folder

Comment: `<clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>` was enough for me in my case.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be achieved by specifying stale file name for schemas and not clearing output directory. The default out put directory is automatically included in classpath which is little convenient. If we specify different output directory one has to take care of classpath to use this code in IDE. For example -

```xml
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                <arguments>-mark-generated</arguments>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>reportingSchema</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/r17/schemaReporting</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>OCISchemaReporting.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <packageName>com.broadsoft.oci.r17.reporting</packageName>
                        <staleFile>${build.directory}/generated-sources/.jaxb-staleFlag-reporting</staleFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemaAS</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/r17/schemaAS</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>OCISchemaAS.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <packageName>com.broadsoft.oci.r17.as</packageName>
                        <staleFile>${build.directory}/generated-sources/.jaxb-staleFlag-as</staleFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Source:[Generating Code with JAXB Plugin](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2010/11/maven-generating-code-with-jaxb-maven.html)

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me, after much trial

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>xjc1</id>
              <goals>
                  <goal>xjc</goal>
              </goals>
             <configuration>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.clientSummary</packageName>
               <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                <sources>
                <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/GetClientSummary.wsdl</source>
                </sources>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjb</outputDirectory>
                 <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
             <id>xjc2</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>xjc</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.wsclient.employerProfile</packageName>
                <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                <sources>
                <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/GetEmployerProfile.wsdl</source>
                </sources>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjb</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
         </configuration>
         </execution>

         <execution>
            <id>xjc3</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.wsclient.producersLicenseData</packageName>
                <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                <sources>
                <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/GetProducersLicenseData.wsdl</source>
                </sources>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjb</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>


     </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

[This is fixed in version 1.6 of the plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608289/jaxb2-maven-plugin-only-executing-first-execution).

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
```

Quick note though, I noticed that the first iteration output was being deleted. I fixed it by adding the following to each of the executions.

```
                        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
```

Here is my full working example with each iteration outputting correctly. BTW I had to do this due to a duplicate namespace problem with the xsd's I was given. This seems to resolve my problem.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>submitOrderRequest</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                        <!-- <schemaFiles>getOrderStatusResponse.xsd,quoteShippingRequest.xsd,quoteShippingResponse.xsd,submitOrderRequest.xsd,submitOrderResponse.xsd</schemaFiles> -->
                        <schemaFiles>submitOrderRequest.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingFiles>submitOrderRequest.xjb</bindingFiles>
                        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>submitOrderResponse</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                        <!-- <schemaFiles>getOrderStatusResponse.xsd,quoteShippingRequest.xsd,quoteShippingResponse.xsd,submitOrderRequest.xsd,submitOrderResponse.xsd</schemaFiles> -->
                        <schemaFiles>submitOrderResponse.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingFiles>submitOrderResponse.xjb</bindingFiles>
                        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a lot of problems when using jaxb in Maven but i managed to solve your problem by doing the following

First create a schema.xjc file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="YOUR_URL?wsdl#types?schema1">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="your.package.name.schema1"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="YOUR_URL??wsdl#types?schema2">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="your.package.name.schema2"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The package name can be anything you want it to be, as long as it doesn't contain any reserved keywords in Java

Next you have to create the wsimport.bat script to generate your packaged and code at the preferred location.

```
cd C:\YOUR\PATH\TO\PLACE\THE\PACKAGES
wsimport -keep -verbose -b "C:\YOUR\PATH\TO\schema.xjb" YOUR_URL?wsdl
pause
```

---

If you do not want to use cd, you can put the wsimport.bat in "C:\YOUR\PATH\TO\PLACE\THE\PACKAGES"

If you run it without -keep -verbose it will only generate the packages but not the .java files.

The -b will make sure the schema.xjc is used when generating

Answer (score 0):

There is another, a clear one (IMO) solution to this
There is a parameter called ["staleFile"](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html) that uses as a flag to not generate stuff again. Simply alter it in each execution.