# generating classes in different packages using jaxb and maven

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857081/how-can-i-tell-jaxb-maven-to-genereate-multiple-schema-packages) but my case is a bit different

I have a single directory which contains many xsd and wsdl. some of these need to be generated into different packages.

I have configured my pom.xml as following:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xsd-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xsdClasses</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.common.serviceinterface.databinding.jaxb</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>resources/webservices</schemaDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <!-- we have 3 top level xsd's -->
                            <include>Topology-Types.xsd</include>
                            <include>Reservation-Types.xsd</include>
                            <include>Notification-Types.xsd</include>

                        </includeSchemas>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg> <!-- to make them implement java.lang.Cloneable -->
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <!-- necesary for -Xcopyable to work -->
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                <version>0.5.3</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>wsdl-reservation-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/reservationClasses</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.common.serviceinterface.reservation</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>resources/webservices/</schemaDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <include>Reservation-WS.wsdl</include>
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>wsdl-notification-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/notificationClasses</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.common.serviceinterface.notification</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>resources/webservices</schemaDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <include>Notification-WS.wsdl</include>
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>wsdl-topology-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/topologyClasses</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.common.serviceinterface.topology</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>resources/webservices</schemaDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <include>Topology-WS.wsdl</include>
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

when I run mvn compile the classes are generated, the problem is that every generated package contains every single class, and not just the one I included wih includeSchemas.

how can I configure the plugin so that every package contains only the classes listed in includeSchemas?

why is my case different to the other question? I cannot put the xsd/wsdl files in different directories since them depend in extra files which I do not think is a good idea to duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `<includeSchemas>` should be `<schemaIncludes>` (at least with version 0.8.0)

Comment: thanks. I got confused with the documentation . I didnt realize there are many jaxb plugins with very similar name