# maven-jaxb2-plugin execute only the first occurence of the Execution

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version> -->
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- <execution>
                    <id>kyc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>net.nationalpayment.core.services.external.exp</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/kyc/</schemaDirectory>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> -->
                <!-- <execution>
                    <id>push-notifications</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.bancbox.schema.notifications.push</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/push-notifications/</schemaDirectory>
                        <includeBindings>
                            <includeBinding>bindings.xjb</includeBinding>
                        </includeBindings>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> -->
                <execution>
                    <id>activity-status</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.bancbox.schema.notifications.activitystatus</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/activity-status/</schemaDirectory>
                        <!-- <includeBindings>
                                     <includeBinding>bindings.xjb</includeBinding>
                        </includeBindings>-->
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I was using `com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2` earlier in my project. I am trying to migrate to org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2. But Java file are not generated for all Execution tags.Only the first execution tag works leaving all others. When I keep only one execution tag by commenting all remaining others. It works fine for all of them one by one. How can we make it work for all instances of execution tag.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857081/how-can-i-tell-jaxb-maven-to-generate-multiple-schema-packages

Comment: Well thanks for the pointer. Now it is working.