# JAXB: Incorrect Namespace Prefix

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces, maven-jaxb2-plugin

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-config</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                </args>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>config/main-config.xsd</include>
                    <include>config/status.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb/config</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <bindingInclude>config-bindings.xjb</bindingInclude>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjc/config</generateDirectory>
                <generatePackage>com.core.config</generatePackage>
                <packageLevelAnnotations>true</packageLevelAnnotations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**config-bindings.xjb:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        version="2.1"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

    <jaxb:bindings >
        <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../xsd/config/config.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='Configuration']">
                <annox:annotate>
                    <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="Conf"/>
                </annox:annotate>
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>

        <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../xsd/config/status.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='StatusInfo']">
                <annox:annotate>
                    <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="Status"/>
                </annox:annotate>
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Auto generated **package-info.java:**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.company.com/configuration", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.core.config;
```

**config.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:cfg="http://www.company.com/configuration"
           targetNamespace="http://www.company.com/configuration"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
>

    <xs:element name="Conf" type="cfg:Configuration">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Root element for the XML configuration.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Configuration">
        //My future Java Bean
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**status.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:cfg="http://www.company.com/configuration-status"
           targetNamespace="http://www.company.com/configuration-status"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
>

    <xs:element name="Status" type="cfg:StatusInfo">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Root element for the XML configuration.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="StatusInfo">
        //My future Java Bean
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I make 
`marshaller.marshal(config, writer);` and it generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Status xmlns="http://www.company.com/configuration-status" xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/configuration">
    <Test></Test>
</ns2:Status>
```

When I make `unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);`

And got the exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 162; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ns2:Status'.
```

So it just mixed namespaces and set incorrect prefix *"ns2"* for the *XmlRootElement*. **Status** element should point to the *xmlns="http://www.company.com/configuration-status"* not to the *xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/configuration"*.
I don't know why it happened. Also I tried to hardcode xml manually before unmarshal it and get the similar SAXParseException.

I've played with different examples how to manually track namespaces by `extends NamespacePrefixMapper` and prefixed by `extends XMLFilterImpl` or/and `extends DefaultHandler` but unfortunately these don't help me.

Comment: You created all classes under `com.core.config` so you cannot have two different `package-info.java` indeed has been replaced with the last one. Try to remove `<generatePackage>com.core.config</generatePackage>`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, U save me one more day:).I've done it by this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857613/3343155 and that solved my problem.